# How to add compatible depencencies for Hibernate 4 Spring 3 and Spring security 3

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-3, hibernate-4.x

I have difficulties finding right version of libraries , I'm using Hibernate4 and spring 3 with spring security.
I'h changed versions several times to match them,but I get several error, hibernate4 error , spring core error ..., anyway
this is my pom working pom without SpringSecurity

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <spring.framework.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <!-- JBoss repository for Hibernate -->
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>


    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL database driver 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <!-- ORACLE database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I add following Spring security dependencies I got this Error:Description Resource Path    Location    Type Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for org/springframework/beans/factory/Aware   servlet-context.xml ..../webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet   line 20 Spring AOP Problem

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
     </dependency> 
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
      </dependency> 
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: Try checking the dependency tree for any version conflicts occuring within the Spring parts you are using. Looks like you are either missing a jar file in your repository or there is some conflict between the something like spring core loading/needing an older version of spring security than you need. Actually I have a working config, that of pretty much the same set up. But unfortunately I can't access it before Monday.Also please post the complete Stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you, there is no Stacktrace actually (Build problems) ,I found out that there is no hope if i want to use Hibernate4 , SpringCore 3.1.1 and SpringSecurity 3.1.4 ,because SpringSecurity3.1.4 is based on SpringCore 3.0.7+. I guess I should downgrade the hibernate to version 3.

Comment: Even if it is probably to late here is what I am using: Hibernate 4.2, Spring Security 3.1.3 and Spring 3.1.1.